# I got this error: Error 1: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[][]' to 'double[]'

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I got this code:

```
double[][] ou = new double[h][w];

for(i=0;i<h;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
      ou[i][j] = sortie[z++];

return ou;
```

And I get this 2 errors:

```
Error 1: Cannot implicitly convert type 'double[][]' to 'double[]'
```

referred to "return ou"

```
Error 2: Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'
```

referred to "double[][] ou = new double[h][w];"

EDIT:
I try to convert a code from Java to C# and that is were I have                  "double[][] ou = new double[h][w];"

Comment: What does the signature of this function look like? Rather, what are you trying to do with it? I'm assuming the function looks as so: `double[] myFunction(...)`. That is, it's supposed to return a a one-dimensional array whereas you are returning `ou`, which is two-dimensional.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Do you have a question, or are you just informing us how smart the compiler is?

Comment: Will C# do `new double[h][w]`?  In other languages, you're expected to do like `new double[][3]` (or `new double[3][]`), and then create each sub-array yourself.

Comment: Sapph, you were right...my function is double[][] myFunction(...)...that error is solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double[,] ou = new double[h,w];
for(i=0;i<h;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<w;j++)
          ou[i,j] = sortie[z++];

return ou;
```

The syntax for a multi-dimensional array uses a comma between the dimensions, not double-brackets.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is a multidimentional array but are creating a Jagged array which is an Array of Array. Look at this SO question for differences.

[Multidimentional Arrays and Jagged Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimentional-array)

So in first line itself you cant create an array with `new double[h][w]` which is not allowed

you need to creae the array like this

```
double[,] array = new double [h,w];
```

and access elements like this

```
array[i,j] = somevalue;
```