# Differences between jagged array and multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

What are the differences between using a jagged array (array of arrays) and a multidimensional array? I'm mostly looking for when to use one over the other.

Array.Copy as an example seems to work just fine with an array of arrays, but I don't know if it's even possible to use a similar mechanic as flexibly with a multidimensional array.

Would an array of arrays be faster for the compiler in C# since the compiler is optimized for single dimensional arrays?

Comment: [What is differences between Multidimensional array and Array of Arrays in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c)

Comment: [Why we have both jagged array and multidimentional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimentional-array)

Comment: See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/08/are-jagged-arrays-faster-than-rectangular-arrays/ for a little info on the relative speed of the two array types.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. I definitely have my answer now. :)