# difference between double[*,*] to double[][] in c#

Tags: c#

i used

```
double [,] marks=new double[26,5] 
int[] function = object.verify(marks) 

public void verifymarks(double[][] marks)
```

error i get is cannot convert from double[*,*] to double[][]
i tried to search in the internet but couldnot find any solution. I have just began to use c#. Please Help. THankx in advance

Comment: First one is JaggedArray and the second one is 2D-Array. Now search by these names.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimentional-array

Comment: if both of them are array and of same data type why can't i use jaggedarray[5][1]=multidimarray[5,1]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`double[][]` is jagged. It's literally an array of arrays.

`double[,]` is multidimensional. It gets special compiler treatment.

They have different memory layouts. `double[][]` is an array which holds references to the other arrays, while `double[,]` is laid out single-dimensionally for easier use.

Another difference is what data they can hold. A jagged array can be like this:

```
1231243245345345345345
23423423423423
2342342343r234234234234234234
23423
```

While a multidimensional array has to be a perfect table, like this:

```
34534534534534
34534534534533
34534534534534
34534534534545
```

A way to get around it would be to use nullable `int`s.

Now, to solve your problem:

Change your method signature to `public void verifymarks(double[,] marks)` and in the method change anything that uses `marks[x][y]` to `marks[x,y]`.

Comment: Can you expand on the "gets special compiler treatment" part? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @Gray I'll try to, but the better person to ask that to is Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 4):

`double[][]` is called a [Jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). It is an array of array (the same way you could create a list of list). With this structure you can specify a different size for each sub-array.

For exemple:

```
double[][] jaggedArray = new double[2][];
jaggedArray[0] = new double[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new double[151];
```

The other writing `double[,]` is a 2D array ([Multidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) in general). You can see it as a table.

A very handy feature of multidimensional array is the initialization:

```
string[,] test = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, 
                                    { "three", "four" },
                                    { "five", "six" } };
```

Comment: if both of them are array why can't i use jaggedarray[5][1]=multidimarray[5,1]

Comment: if `jaggedarray` and `multidimarray` contains the same data type it should work.

Comment: i tried double[][] jaggedarray=new double[27][];
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            jaggedarray[j][0] = values[j, 0];
            jaggedarray[j][1] = values[j, 3];
        } _but it did not work_ both of them are double

Comment: Because `jaggedarray[j]` is not initialized.
You have to do `jaggedarray[j] = new double[2]` for each `j`. Before accessing its elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a visual, from LINQPad's `Dump()` function.

[image]

The first is the `double[,]`, which creates a matrix.  The second is `double[][]`, which is just an array of arrays.