# What does double[,,] represent?

Tags: c#

In answering [a question about `double[,]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17795560/298754), I added a screenshot of LINQPad's output for that data structure:

[image: double[,]]

However, I got to wondering what a `double[,,]` looks like, and LINQPad won't visualize it for me.  Additionally, I don't understand the format of the data which goes into it:

```
   int[,,] foo = new int[,,]
   { 
     { 
        { 2, 3}, 
        { 3, 4}
     },
     { 
        { 3, 4},
        { 1, 5} 
     }
   };
```

Can anyone visualize this for me?

Comment: I think the most direct way to visualize it would be with a 3D cube. I don't know if anyone wants to suggest a complicated 2D model...?

Comment: @Katana314, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18304657/129164 for what I think would technically be considered a *1D* model.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can think of this has having a set of tables stacked on top of each other.  So you would need to specify a triplet to retrieve the item, which would specify which table, column, and row to get the value from.

Here's what a 3x3x3 array can be visualized as:

[image]

Comment: And each box holds one number of the input? **Edit:** Based on @Servy's comment on his answer, I know the answer to my question is "Yes".

Comment: Correct.  Each box is an array location, which would then hold a value (a double if you used your example).

Comment: Please visualize `double[,,,,,,]` as well ;-)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: `double[,,,]` can be visualized as a group of the 3D tables PocketDews drew for us. `double[,,,,]` can be visualized as a group of those groups. `double[,,,,,]` can be seen as a group of *those* groups (perhaps organized as a cube made up of PocketDew's cubes). `double[,,,,,,]` can be visualized as a group of *those* groups - and so on, indefinitely.

Comment: Nothing easier to visualize than a 7-dimensional structure!

Answer (score 9):

It's a [Rectangular Cuboid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid).

It's a three dimensional solid with 6 faces, all being rectangles.

You can further imagine that cuboid being broken up into a number of cubes, and each of those cubes having a single value.

Comment: So where is the pair `{2, 3}` (for instance)?  A pair of adjoining cubes? The line between two corners?

Comment: @Bobson In your example you have 8 different values, which is a 2x2x2 cube.  `{ 2, 3}, { 3, 4}` represents the bottom half of the cube, and `{ 2, 3}` represents to adjoining cubes (making up 1/4 of the entire cube).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.

Answer (score 8):

It's a 3D array. So you have to do a 3D representation to visualize it.

You can think of creating a cube (or more correctly a Rectangular cuboid) with multiple Lego bricks where each brick contains 1 integer.

Comment: It's not a cube, as the dimensions don't all need to be equal.  It's a cuboid.

Comment: Yes, but I don't now if everybody knows what a cuboid is.

Comment: If you can use another term to represent what you mean, then by all means, but saying that it is a cube is not correct.

Comment: Actually if you represent the array values as cuboids rather than cubes, it would be possible to squash them to fit a cube-shaped container even if the dimensions of the array are unequal. Just sayin' :P

Comment: @JonathanGraef Just change the size of the Lego bricks :D

Answer (score 3):

That would be a cuboid (3-dimensional Array)- this goes as deep as you like (dimension wise), but visualization becomes really hard after the 3rd dimension.

You could imagine it as a stack of tables of the given kind; that analogy works recursively.

Answer (score 3):

It's 3D array (array of 2D arrays) as others said. You can use [this extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eedc48e7-5169-40d3-b602-ad451990a420) for visualization.

Comment: Ooooh, that looks fun to play with.

Answer (score 1):

It's also quite possible to represent an n-dimensional array in a "pivoted" format, such as this:

[image]

This is one of the easier formats to generate and read for an array with more than two dimensions.

Comment: Nice one.  I wish LINQPad printed it out this way.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional Array look like a cube  with 6side and have  3 property width ,height,and depth , when u detrminet depth u put the page of 2dimension array  in real when 2d array have depth more than 1  we create 3d array . look this [Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLAP_cube) For know in depth this concept. and this article for use in [Programming](http://zetcode.com/lang/csharp/arrays/)