# Value of typeof(int[][]).GetArrayRank() is 1

Tags: c#

Why is the value of `typeof(int[][]).GetArrayRank() = 1`, and how to create to Jagged array by reflection?

```
typeof(int[][]).GetArrayRank();//1.
```

Comment: [Same question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a07e6138-ccf2-4015-846c-df0cf2fedb27/creating-jagged-arrays-through-reflection?forum=netfxbcl) but not at SO.

Comment: Because jagged array is one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 5):

A jagged array (`int[][]`) is different from a multidimensional array (`int[,]`):

```
var jagged = typeof(int[][]);
var multiDimensional = typeof(int[,]);

Console.WriteLine("Jagged: " + jagged.GetArrayRank()); // 1
Console.WriteLine("Multidimensional: " + multiDimensional.GetArrayRank()); // 2
```

To create a jagged array using reflection, you have to cobble it together from these resources:

- [How can I dynamically generate and populate a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487285/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-and-populate-a-multi-dimensional-array)
- [How do I create a C# array using Reflection and only type info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419456/how-do-i-create-a-c-sharp-array-using-reflection-and-only-type-info)
- [Setting value in an array via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783191/setting-value-in-an-array-via-reflection)

First get the type information:

```
var typeOfInt = typeof(int);
var typeOfIntArray = typeOfInt.MakeArrayType();
var typeOfArrayOfIntArrays = typeOfIntArray.MakeArrayType();

Console.WriteLine(typeOfArrayOfIntArrays); // System.Int32[][]
```

Then instantiate and populate it:

```
// The root array has one element
var arrayOfIntArrays = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfArrayOfIntArrays, 1);
// The inner array has two elements
var intArray = (Array)Activator.CreateInstance(typeOfIntArray, 2);

intArray.SetValue(42, 0);
intArray.SetValue(21, 1);

arrayOfIntArrays.SetValue(intArray, 0);

foreach (Array arr in arrayOfIntArrays)
{
    foreach (var value in arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "*to create a multidimensional array using reflection...*"?

Comment: @canton I've updated the answer. The answers I link to don't deal with jagged arrays.

Comment: @canton7 typeof(int).MakeArrayType(dimension)

Comment: @yijiemanong Why the mention? My point was that he said "*To create a jagged array using reflection*" and then linked to a page which describes how to create a multidimensional array using reflection. He's since updated his answer with sample code to create a jagged array, so all is good.