# Is there a way to get the object located in the coordinates retrieved from a 2d array to compare it?

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print the coordinates if my object is found in the 2D array. Am using .Equals but it seems to be ignoring it.

```
    private void PrintCarInfo(Car car, object[,] matrix)
    {
        int xCoordinate = 0;
        int yCoordinate = 0;

        int w = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int h = matrix.GetLength(1);

        for (int x = 0; x < w; ++x)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < h; ++y)
            {
                if (matrix[x, y].Equals(car))
                {
                    xCoordinate = x;
                    yCoordinate = y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Car class:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Manual { get; set; }

    public bool Diesel { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {

    }

    public Car(Car car)
    {
        Index = car.Index;
        Name = car.Name;
        Manual = car.Manual;
        Diesel = car.Diesel;
    }
}
```

This is what I get when debug from the 2D array:

```
[1,1] {Toyota (15)}
```

Comment: If you don't override `Equals` then an object won't be equal unless it is the actual same instance, even if all the properties are equal.

Comment: As an aside, I'd prefer a [jagged array to a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimensional-array).

Comment: @Jodrell - jagged (array-of-array) is a little faster but unless there is a direct need for a non-rectangular shape I would prefer multi dim. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

> Am using .Equals but it seems to be ignoring it.

Yes,

```
 if (matrix[x, y].Equals(car))
```

will only work

1. When `car` is a reference to an instance in the matrix, or
2. When you override Car.Equals

The default comparison for classes is Reference Equality. That will only work when the search element `car` is the exact same object as is in the matrix.

When you want to compare to a different object but with the same property values, you will have to implement Equality by yourself.

Comment: 3. use of value type / struct

Comment: @fubo - `Car` is a `class`. And I wouldn't encourage making it a struct.

Comment: my fault - it seemed to me that you wanted to numerate all possible ways how `Equals()` would work and I just wanted to add another option

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve and compare using just one attribute from the whole object? meaning if the index is the same, true

Comment: Sure, `if (matrix[x, y].Index == car.Index)`

Comment: it won't let me because object[,] is being passed not Car[,]

Comment: No mention of `obj[,]`  in the question. Rethink your entire setup and dataflow.

Comment: It becomes `if (((Car)matrix[x, y]).Index == car.Index)`