# Argument 1: Cannot convert from 'int[][]' to 'int[*,*]'

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an app that adds the lines and columns of a matrix. The logic behind the app is that you input in a textbox each line of the matrix on a single line and separate every line with "/". For example: 1 2 3 4/1 2 3 4. Im trying to convert the values from string to int but I keep getting the argument 1 error.

Edit: forgot to add the function for the adding of the rows.

```
if (decision == 2)
{
    string[] tokens = a.Split('/');
    int[][] tokens1 = new int[][] {
        tokens[0].Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray(),
        tokens[1].Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToArray()
    };

    row_sum(tokens1, 2);
}

static void row_sum(int[,] arr, int orden)
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;

    // finding the row sum 
    for (i = 0; i < orden; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < orden; ++j)
        {

            // Add the element 
            sum = sum + arr[i, j];
        }

        // Print the row sum 
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the row " +
                             i + " = " + sum);

        // Reset the sum 
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: A [multidimensional array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) is not the same as a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays). In the first part, you use a jagged array (`tokens1`) and in the second one (in the `row_sum` method, variable `arr`), you're using a multidimensional array. You have to use the same in both places, otherwise you'll get that compiler error you're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're dealing with two different kinds of arrays:

- `tokens1` is a jagged array (`int[][]`): it is an array of arrays. The child array at `tokens1[0]` can be a different length to the array at `tokens1[1]`.
- `arr` is a 2d array. The dimensions are pre-defined and the length of the second bound never changes based on the first.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimensional-array) for more information on 2d arrays vs jagged arrays.

The solution to your problem is to make `row_sum` accept the same kind of array as you're creating, or create the same kind of array as `row_sum` accepts.

The easiest option is, perhaps, to make `row_sum` accept a jagged array:

```
 static void row_sum(int[][] arr)
 {

    int i, j, sum = 0;

    // finding the row sum 
    for (i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; ++j)
        {

            // Add the element 
            sum = sum + arr[i][j];
        }

        // Print the row sum 
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the row " +
                             i + " = " + sum);


        // Reset the sum 
        sum = 0;
    }
 }
```

I took the liberty of removing the length value since it's not required as this information can be obtained from the array itself.