# i need java array to csharp

Tags: java, c#, arrays

i want to write this code( java ) on c# , but receive this error message

Unable to cast object of type 'System.SByte[,]' to type 'System.SByte[][]'.

java code is :

```
byte[][] bArr2 = (byte[][]) Array.newInstance(byte.class, new int[]{2, 8});
```

my csharp code is

```
sbyte[][] bArr2 = (sbyte[][])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(sbyte), new int[] { 2, 8 });
```

thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know the dimensions. So you should just declare the array normally.

Java:

```
byte[][] bArr2 = new byte[2][8];
```

C#:

```
sbyte[,] bArr2 = new sbyte[2,8];
```

In general, when porting between languages, I recommend to keep the standard language docs open so you can learn about the basic syntax like this (`sbyte[,]`).

Comment: `  byte[] bArr3 = new byte[8];
   bArr2[1] = bArr3;
`

Comment: if use [,] array , how to bArr3 into bArr2[1] ? i dont understand it ,

Comment: See answers to [Multidimensional Array \[\]\[\] vs \[,\]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12567378/666583). You would need to make a jagged array if you want to work with individual sub-arrays like that. But making that change, you would no longer be working with a strongly-typed 2-D array, i.e., you would lose some type safety. Are you sure you need `bArr3` at all? Instead, you should be able to work with the elements of `bArr2` directly. Java does not have this feature.