# swift two dimensional array of unknown size to c#

Tags: c#, swift, xamarin.ios

I'm having difficulties wrapping my head around two dimensional array in Swift and how to convert it to c# Xamarin iOS.

The [code](https://gist.github.com/smswz/393b2d6237b7837234015805c600ada2#file-gridlayout-swift-L78) is the following:

```
/// This represents a 2 dimensional array for each section, indicating whether each block in the grid is occupied
/// It is grown dynamically as needed to fit every item into a grid
private var sectionedItemGrid: Array<Array<Array<Bool>>> = []
```

Is it not a 3 dimensional bool array?

What would be the c# equivalent?

I guess I should use a List instead. But what would be T exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that that's 3D, not 2D. (i.e. a 2D array *for each section*)

Swift does not have multidimensional (rectangular) arrays, like C# offers. Only jagged arrays.

[Why we have both jagged array and multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimensional-array)

The closest equivalent is, as you suspected `List<List<List<bool>>>`.