# How to initialize a two dimension array for a Matrix class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

**Problem**

I am writing a Matrix class in C# and I know that this class needs a two dimension array to store the Matrix object. The constructor for my Matrix class takes two parameters, the m and n dimensions of the Matrix. I have tried to assign the array inside the constructor but I get the error that
`Invalid Rank Specifier`. The code I tried is listed below.

```
class Matrix
    {
        //make the dimensions private
        private int m,n;

        //The Matrix constructor needs two parameters
        //The row and column dimensions
        //declare the two dimension array
        private int[][] array;
        public Matrix(int m, int n) {
          //assign the array inside the constructor
            array = new int[m][n];
        }
        //method to allocate the Matrix
    }
```

My goal is to initialize the array with the dimensions first so that assigning can be done without errors, Thank You.

Comment: First option is use a multidimensional array instead of a jagged array, Second, use a loop to allocate each leaf array

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica, but I just initialized to it  using the new keyword following the array that needs to be stored in that object

Comment: [See also here: jagged vs multidimensional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648914/why-we-have-both-jagged-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @ChrᴉzremembersMonica, opened the link, its the same exact problem , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a *jagged array*, i.e. *array of array*: `int[][]`, note that *2d array* is `int[,]`

To initialize `int[][]` you have to create each inner array:

```
 public Matrix(int m, int n) {
   array = new int[m][];         // outer array of size m which

   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)   // contains
     array[i] = new int[n];      // arrays of length n 
 }
```

You can use *Linq* for shorter syntax:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 public Matrix(int m, int n) {
   array = Enumerable
     .Range(0, m)
     .Select(_ => new int[n])
     .ToArray();
 }
```

**Edit:** Possible `Matrix` implementation:

```
  class Matrix {
    private int[][] array;

    public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
      if (rows <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rows));
      if (columns <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(columns));

      array = Enumerable
        .Range(0, rows)
        .Select(_ => new int[columns])
        .ToArray();
    }

    public int RowCount => array.Length;

    public int ColumnCount => array[0].Length;

    public int this[int row, int column] {
      get {
        if (row < 0 || row >= array.Length)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row));
        if (column < 0 || column >= array[row].Length)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column));

        return array[row][column];
      }
      set {
        if (row < 0 || row >= array.Length)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row));
        if (column < 0 || column >= array[row].Length)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(column));

        array[row][column] = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is a jagged array?

Comment: Am trying to assign to the array and am getting this error, `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an object of type Matrix`, I tried assigning to a certain index  like this
`Matrix A = new Matrix(4,4);
A[0][0]
`

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU: jagged array is an *array of arrays*: note that inner arrays can be of *different* lengths: `int[][] array = new int[][] {new int[] {1, 2, 3}, new int[] {4}, new int[] {5, 6}};`

Comment: recheck my first comment, am getting an error trying to assign after creating a 4 by 4 array Matrix

Comment: Okay, my bad, l need to access the array inside the Matrix object and assign, How do we assign multidimension arrays?

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU: multidimensional array (2d array in your case) is declared as `int[,] array;`initialized as `array = new int[m, n];` addressed as `array[y, x];`. Jagged array is decalared as `int[][] array;`, initialized as in my answer above, addressed as `array[y][x];`

Comment: I did `A.array[0,0]=2` and it works for some reason, is this the same as `A[0][0]=2` in the same context but with other programming languages?

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU: it can work in some C language compilers

Comment: Am lost, Is there a way to make the in-built Matrix class of the C# language accept two parameters am trying to do a transform and I need to access the inverse of a matrix which I have realized my current class does not have? namespace `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix`

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU: I've provided simple `Matrix` implementation; note that if you want *inverse* matrix you should operate with *floating point* values.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like what you are trying to do is create a multi dimensional array, which you can learn more about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

In your case this would mean that you would create an int[,] array as such:

```
class Matrix
{
    //make the dimensions private
    private int m,n;

    //The Matrix constructor needs two parameters
    //The row and column dimensions
    //declare the two dimension array
    private int[,] array;
    public Matrix(int m, int n) {
      //assign the array inside the constructor
        array = new int[m, n];
    }
    //method to allocate the Matrix
}
```

After that you can access your values through:

```
public int GetValue(int m, int n) => array[m,n];
```

And equally for settings values:

```
public void SetValue(int m, int n) => array[m,n] = value;
```

Comment: Okay, can you edit the method for setting values to use a loop, i just want to understand how the iteration is performed to achieve a successful assignment

Comment: I tried to assign after creating a new Matrix object and i got an error that `cannot apply indexing with [] to an object of type Matrix`. I tried to assign like this
`Matrix A = new Matrix(4,4)`;
`A[0][0]=2;`Can you help me figure out why that is?

Comment: If you want to iterate through a multidimension array you can do:
`for(int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
Console.WriteLine(array[i,0])
}`
However if you want to iterate through all of dimensions and all elements you can do something likes this:



`for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
for(int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(1); x++)`

Comment: @RóbertPécz, did you check the constructor in my Matrix class?The constructor is everything, I will use that to initialize the array outside the class

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a regular 1D array for 2D data. Something like:

```
public class MyMatrix<T> 
{
        public int Width { get; }
        public int Height { get; }
        public T[] Data { get; }
        public MyMatrix(int width, int height)
        {
            Width = width;
            Height = height;
            Data = new T[width * height];
        }
        public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get => Data[y * Width + x];
            set => Data[y * Width + x] = value;
        }
}
```

This has some advantages over the typical 2D Multidimensional approach:

- Interoperability: Multidimensional arrays are a .Net concept that does not exist in every language, but just about every language have some sort of 1D array.
- Serialization: Most serialization libraries handle 1D arrays, support for 2D arrays are more spotty.
- Performance: Sometimes you just need to iterate over all the items, using the backing 1D arrays is probably the fastest way to do this.
- Avoiding pitfals: `.GetLength()` for multidimensional arrays is quite slow, not a large problem if you cache the values outside your loop, but can be a problem if you do not know about this, or forget.

Comment: Wow, trying this out, looks safe and easy to implement, am having an issue with the assignment of a certain index `A[0][0]` in the array, compiler says `cannot apply indexing with [] to an object of type Matrix`, I hope your code will work.

Comment: What version of .Net does this run on again, am getting an error in the getters and setters that only specific `assignment, call, increment, decrement, call can be used as statement`

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU indexing is done like `[x, y]` not `[x][y]`. Not sure about the error, but it will require c# 7 for the expression bodied properties, but you should be able to just use regular setters/getters. I.e.  `get{return Data[y * Width + x];}`

Comment: you know you need to edit your answer so it becomes easier for me

Comment: @KINYUA TIMOTHY NJIRU the example code is perfectly fine as it is in any recent version of c#. I do not see it as very helpful overall to use examples using first version of the language since it lacks even basic features like generics.